# Sending an SMS with Swift, remember phone number

Tags: swift

I'm working on an app where you can send an sms to someone within the app. This is what I've found so far. I would like to remember the phone number once it has been entered for the future, though the user has the ability to change it whenever they want to. Any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumber: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func sendText(sender: UIButton) {
    if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
        let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        controller.body = "Message Body"
        controller.recipients = [phoneNumber.text]
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
    //... handle sms screen actions
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save phone number in nsuser default. and when you need that number you can retrive from Nsuser default

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(phoneNumber.text, forKey: "phone_no")
```

by above line you can store mobile number in nsuserDefault

then you can retrive it by this code

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("phone_no")
```

you can replace your function with this

```
@IBAction func sendText(sender: UIButton) {
    if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
        let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        controller.body = "Message Body"
        if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("phone_no") != nil)
        {
            controller.recipients = [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("phone_no")]
        }
        else
        {
            controller.recipients = [phoneNumber.text]
        }

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(phoneNumber.text, forKey: "phone_no")
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. So how would you go about it and where do I add this?

Answer (score 0):

Worked on something like this awhile ago, here's a thought:

You can save phoneNumber.text as a variable and then (maybe after successful completion of the text message being sent) then save it in either a database (Realm perhaps) or using the apps data (NSCoding).

Then, you'll have a place where the number is stored and can then compare any new number put in the text field in the future.